# How to configure Vue router to respond to query strings?

Tags: javascript, router, vue-router, vue.js

My router in configured as follows. It works and does what it's supposed to.

```
import Demo1 from "../vuex_modules/demo/demo1.vue"
import Demo2 from "../vuex_modules/demo/demo2.vue"

export const routes = [
  { path: "/demo/demo1", component: Demo1 },
  { path: "/demo/demo2", component: Demo2 }
];
```

Now, I need to match me some query strings. When I click in one of the views routed to above, I want the object pushed to the router to look like this.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    clicky: function(row) {
      this.$router.push({ path: "", query: { id: row } });
    }
  }
}
```

I want the new URL, with *?id=123* added, to lead to another page (while *demo2.vue* is the table view, *demo2_id.vue* is supposed to be displayed upon a click and present details for the particular row being clicked.

According to [Vue router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), I'm suppose to add a colon when a part of URL is dynamic. I've tried different approaches, including the one below. I'm not routed to the page requested, though. Instead, I dwell still on the original page.

```
import Demo1 from "../vuex_modules/demo/demo1.vue"
import Demo2 from "../vuex_modules/demo/demo2.vue"
import Demo2_Id from "../vuex_modules/demo/demo2_id.vue"

export const routes = [
  { path: "/demo/demo1", component: Demo1 },
  { path: "/demo/demo2", component: Demo2 },
  { path: "/demo/demo2?:id", component: Demo2_Id }
];
```

Goolearching for *vue router query strings* leads to nothing that I can regard as useful (possibly due to ignorance)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Case 1:

Following routes are two same route:

```
{ path: "/demo/demo2", component: Demo2 },
{ path: "/demo/demo2?:id", component: Demo2_Id }
```

### Case 2:

While following are different:

```
{ path: "/demo/demo2", component: Demo2 },
{ path: "/demo/demo2/:id", component: Demo2_Id }
```

In first case: `/demo/demo2?:id=213`, you can get id as `$route.query.id` while in second case: `/demo/demo2/:id`, you will get id as  `$route.params.id`.

Now if you want to have **routes as in case 1**: You will have single row in routes file and single route:

```
{ path: "/demo/demo2", component: Demo2 },
```

and you can write code to detect whether `$route.query.id` is present or not and load component accordingly with use of [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if)

If you want to have **routes as in case 2**: you can add above two lines in routes file and treat them as two different routes.