# v-link add linkActiveClass ,how to match routerName or (path and query)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have two v-link like this :

```
    '/accountList?accountType=1': {
        name: 'accountList1',
        component: require('./../views/finance/accountList.vue')
    },
    '/accountList?accountType=2': {
        name: 'accountList2',
        component: require('./../views/finance/accountList.vue')
    },

 <li><a v-link=" { name: 'accountList1', exact: true }   "><span>test1</span></a></li>
 <li><a v-link=" { name: 'accountList2', exact: true }   "><span>test2</span></a></li>
```

when i click one or them , both are added linkActiveClass .

[image]

Now,my problem is: how to controller the active status by routerName or path **AND** query?

Ps: exact: true, this is a wrong example,it is not fit here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I see two solutions

1. along with routerName you also need to compare [query](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html) params which can be accessed by: `this.$route.query. accountType`
2. You can compare [$route.fullPath](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html) which includes  URL including query and hash.

But I am not sure why you have these two routes different: ideally these should be ideally same route with different query Param. Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41168266/1610034).

Comment: Now,i controller it in ready hook by handwork, looks like it can't resolve in vue-router? I set this two menus because they are auth for different people.

Comment: I have try three way. the other 2 way is: 1. immediate writhe path in v-link, 2. one router config,add query param in v-link . all of  them have this problem.

Comment: @JsonSong Can you creae a fiddle of it?

Answer (score 0):

Per docs: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html

I would suggest to use:

```
  <!-- with query, resulting in /register?plan=private -->
  <router-link :to="{ path: 'accountType', query: { accountType: '1' }}"></router-link>
<router-link :to="{ path: 'accountType', query: { accountType: '2' }}"></router-link>
```

Comment: this is equivalent to my code. I try it , same result.